# How to redefine constructor of standard function in JS?

Tags: javascript, constructor, redefine

So, I want redefine constructor of HTMLButtonElement with input args. I know how to do this without args:

```
var CButtonPrototype = Object.create(HTMLButtonElement.prototype);
CButtonPrototype.createdCallback = function()
{
  alert("call");
  this.setAttribute("class", "some class");
  this.value = 0;
  this.innerHTML = "some text";
};

var CButton = document.registerElement('cbutton', {
  prototype: CButtonPrototype
});

var myButton = new CButton();
```

And it's works, but I want use this class something like `var myButton = new CButton(arg 1, arg 2, etc);`. This method don't let me doing `CButtonPrototype.createdCallback = function(arg 1, arg2)`. How can I resolve this? Maybe you know another way?

Thanks \o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to extend this type, please consider the following:

```
CButton.prototype.test = function()
{
    console.log(arguments);
}

CButton.prototype.test2 = function(num, str, bool)
{
    console.log(num + ' ' + str + ' ' + bool);
}

myButton.test(20, 'hello', true); //call test function with parameters
myButton.test2(20, 'hello', true); // still the same
```

about your original question:

you can't insert parameters because this "function" is only a delegate to a system function... in your case - an object c'tor.

to test it you can try arguments - a special array inside every function in js that represents the arguments of the function:

```
var CButtonPrototype = Object.create(HTMLButtonElement.prototype);
CButtonPrototype.createdCallback = function()
{
  console.log(arguments); // print arguments to the console screen
  this.setAttribute("class", "some class");
  this.value = 0;
  this.innerHTML = "some text";
};

var CButton = document.registerElement('cbutton', {
  prototype: CButtonPrototype
});

var myButton = new CButton();
```

run this code - you will see an empty array - mainly because your c'tor call 'new CButton()' has no arguments. try to insert arguments and you will get an error.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer :) I knew about prototype functions, but can you  tell me, is  there some other ways to overload c-tor for my needs? Is using prototype func is the better?

Comment: your own c'tor - not a problem. an override c'tor based on dom settings... not so much. can you share what's in your mind for such a demand?

Comment: I want class with methods for buttons. Earlier I trying:
`function CButton(buttonName, functionName, buttonClass)
{
  if (!(this instanceof CButton)) return new CButton(buttonName, functionName);

  this.btn = doc.createElement("button");
  this.btn.setAttribute("class", buttonClass);
  this.btn.setAttribute("onClick", functionName);
  this.btn.innerHTML = buttonName;
}` There other problems, i can't redefine `this` for returning other types (this = doc.createElement("button")). If i would use `return this.btn`, there no sense for using class, it become simple function without methods.

Comment: for that purpose, please implement your own types and don't override the dom (which is full with restrications because of securiy hacks)

Comment: Sorry for my noob's question, but I really can't understood this. For ex. `appendChild` work with only HTMLElement class right? If i create my own, it's didn't work with it, because class should have the same type. I thought that redefinition of standard c-tor will be good idea.

Comment: you can create you own, but not overrding the system configuration... HTML elements c'tor is a very specific part with a very strict implementation